# UITableView separator flickering during app switching

Tags: ios, uitableview

PS: I can post a small video but it seems unnecessary.

Create a sample project using Xcode 6.4 (currently using `6E35b`). Create a simple UITableViewController subclass and render it using either a storyboard or programmatically.

Try app-switching. It appears that the tableview separator flickers whenever the app goes in background or foreground. It doesn't flickr while scrolling, etc.

To see it better, use:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tableView.rowHeight = 75.0f
self.tableView.separatorColor = self.view.tintColor;
```

I am unsure why this is happening. I have referred to [iPhone 6/6 Plus: UITableView separator flickering and different thickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502773/iphone-6-6-plus-uitableview-separator-flickering-and-different-thickness) but the default projects always have a launch screen IB file.

You can see the issue in the default settings app on iOS. For the most part, this doesn't become an issue unless you are rendering images and suddenly the white separator lines flickr.

**EDIT 1:** The biggest issue for me is that even if I use:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

the separator is rendered momentarily and then disappears; exactly the same as in other cases. See **EDIT 2** for more details.

**EDIT 2 (07/04/15, 8.46PM):** I wish to provide some more examples here. The flickering behavior that I was observing was much more prominent with custom table view cells (i.e. where you have a freedom of rendering your own image views with custom property settings, etc).

Another observation is that the specific flickering behavior (i.e. in the case where `separatorStyle == UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`) is not noticeable with text only cells. It is primarily noticeable in cases where images are rendered in table view cells.

1. Here is an example of a table view cell:

   ```
   @interface BTableViewCell ()

   @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIImageView *mainImageView;

   @end

   @implementation BTableViewCell

   - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
   {
       self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
       if (self)
       {
           [self commonInit];
       }
       return self;
   }

   - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
   {
       self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
       if (self)
       {
           [self commonInit];
       }
       return self;
   }

   - (void)commonInit
   {
       // Initialize Avatar Image
       self.mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
       _mainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
       _mainImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
       [self.contentView addSubview:_mainImageView];

       [self configureConstraintsForImageView];
   }

   - (void)configureConstraintsForImageView
   {
       [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0]];
       [self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0]];
   }

   @end

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       BTableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

       NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"jpeg"];
       UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
       cell.mainImageView.image = image; //ignore unoptimized load
       return cell;
   }
   ```
2. The flickering almost goes away if `masksToBounds` property is `false`. I am not sure why this would be the case or if this is the intended way.
3. Instead of using a custom table view cell, use the default `UITableViewCell` class.

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

       NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"jpeg"];
       UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
       cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
       return cell;
   }
   ```

It's worth noticing that the flickering behavior for *#2* and *#3* is more or less the same. It is much more subtle as compared to the one in *#1*, but still noticeable.

Comment: I haven't investigated this issue thoroughly yet but the flickering effects in separators was very reminiscent of a problem I encountered with the UISegmentedControl. Maybe that SO conversation will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894772/uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-7-divider-image-is-wrong-during-animation/20654744#20654744

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
Renders with edge antialiasing: YES
```

In your app plist

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue for a while. I did a long research about how I can handle this problem and never found something useful. I came to conclusion that **nobody noticed** and whoever noticed **didnt care** about appswitch table view's 0.6f line. But I found a little workaround if you still ned this. Besides using `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` also do `[self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]]` and the last thing you can do, if you can have a gap between cells like facebook ios app has, then set the background color to some grey color.