# Configuring UISegmentedControl Animation

Tags: ios, animation, uisegmentedcontrol

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/) says

> When you add and remove segments, you can request that the action be
>   animated with sliding and fading effects.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894772/uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios-7-divider-image-is-wrong-during-animation) shows a manual way to remove the animation. But since it is stated in the documentation, shouldn't there be a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable or disable the animation using this methods:

```
- insertSegmentWithImage:atIndex:animated:
– insertSegmentWithTitle:atIndex:animated:
– removeSegmentAtIndex:animated:
```